Desktop 22.04 LTS starts hanging with frozen mouse cursor - only forced reboot helps for it to reoccur!
I am on Ubuntu Desktop 22.04 LTS and I have the described issue since a couple of weeks, without any Nvidia or special graphic card/drivers. My mouse starts hanging, the cursor position is frozen and laptop isn't reacting on any command, be it via mouse, keyboard or touchpad. The only way out it a forced reboot! It reoccurs after a certain while, mostly when actively working again.

Before proceeding with any method, I suggest opening the terminal and writing ls /var/crash: if there are files, run sudo apport-retrace /var/crash/filename.crash for more info.
You can also check the journal with sudo journalctl: here you'll find a report of the events ordered chronologically.
Anyway, these are, from my experience, the most common ways to solve this problem:

Check if the Swap usage is high: in the terminal, run free -h (or equivalently go to the system monitor) and check if Swap usage is high. In that case, you need to extend Swap memory.

Run a MemTest from boot (at least one full test, but more is better). It can be performed while booting: turn on your machine and hold down the Shift key. This will lead you to the grub menu; select memtest86+ and wait until one cycle is completed. This test will tell you if there are some hardware problems (at RAM level).
This tool may not be installed on your pc, so in the terminal write sudo apt install memtest86+ to get it.

Check for Bios Upgrade. This was my case: for now, it seems to have solved the problem. (Be cautious with this: always refer to your hardware manufacturer's instructions).

Upgrade Kernel: if it's not a hardware or memory problem, may be a kernel version issue. In this case, you need simply to run sudo apt update && sudo apt full-upgrade in your terminal. Ubuntu will check if new versions are available.


It can also be due to your graphics card and the drivers you are using; for more info on your card model, go to Settings/Info. If your card is an Intel, you don't need to do anything, else, if it's an Invidia or AMD, you can try to upgrade drivers.
Lastly, you can try switching from Wayland to Xorg. I've read in other forums that this worked for someone, so it may be worth a try.
Note: On crashes, instead of force rebooting, try to reboot the machine safely by holding Alt, then (keeping hold Alt for the entire process) press Syst key (sometimes "Rsyst" on Keyboards) and write "REISUB". As said, this will umount the disk more safely. Of course if the system doesn't respond, you need to force a reboot by pressing the power button.
I hope this helps!

Hello @Fra_liturri, many thanks for your detailed reply to my issue - I tried most of your proposed error resolutions, so far I haven't fully gotten rid of the described issue yet, unfortunately. It might be related to Chromium browser, I noticed it mainly occurs while using it. If nothing else will help, I'll try an upgrade to Ubuntu 2410.1 LTS... Again, many thanks, your help is much appreciated!!! All the best, C.

You're welcome!  Successive versions of Ubuntu may crash as the one you already have, so an upgrade wouldn't solve your problem. For this reason, I suggest leaving this solution as the last: probably some other will help with your issue!
Have you tried to check the log for a crash report? Is RAM usage high? Since your machine crashes while using Chromium I suspect it's a memory problem. Changing your browser to Mozilla Firefox should solve this: it's optimized to use less.
Unfortunately, I'm not able to help more than this, but surely someone will! Best wishes, F.

Hello @Fra_liturri, thanks again for the help. Meanwhile it crashed in Firefox. Unfortunately, I'm unable to start memtest86+. The described holding shift doesn't work upon booting, nor am I able to start it from USB due to ubuntu being shown as only drive for selection of boot prio in BIOS. Pressing esc during start up brings me to Grub menu, but no avail for memtest86+. Changing boot order in efibootmgr didn't work either. Many thanks again, I will keep on trying and will report back in case of error resolution! Best wishes, C!

Hi @Cleeblatt, I'm unable to help with your problem since I've never had an issue with memtest86+: the only suggestion that comes to my mind is to check for the correct version of the utility and this answer How do I run memtest86+. Hope this helps!
